# Color Changing Lines/Plots Based on Time

Tags: plot, time, colors

Trying to figure out how to create a line/plot that changes color over time whether its a millisecond, second, and or minute.

Example would be red at 12 hrs, 0 mins, 0 seconds and 0 milliseconds (12:00:00.00) and then orange at 12:00:00.01, so on with any other color.

I tried using a different color for a previous bar to plot the line but it didnt work out.

Comment: This needs to be in pinescript for tradinview